# Unzip .gz files in different folders and combine them into a single file

Tags: linux, bash, unix, gzip

I have a few .gz files with the same name in different folders. So i want to unzip all these .gz files and combine all the output files into a single file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
find some/dir -name foo.gz -exec zcat {} \; > output.file
```

Answer (score 1):

```
find . -name "xyz.gz"|xargs zcat >output_file
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you do not know the names of the files in advance, you might find the following script helpful. You should run it as `my-script.sh /path/to/search/for/duplicate/names /target/dir/to/create/combined/files`. It finds all the filenames with more than one occurrence in the given path and combines their content into a single file in the target directory.

```
#! /bin/bash
path=$1
target=$2
[[ -d $path   ]] || { echo 'Path not found'   ; exit 1 ; }
[[ -d $target ]] || { echo 'Target not found' ; exit 1; }

find "$path" -name '*.gz' | \
    rev | cut -f1 -d/ | rev | \              # remove the paths
    sort | uniq -c | \                       # count numbers of occurrences
    grep -v '^ *1 ' | \                      # skip the unique files
    while read _num file ; do                # process the files in a loop
    find -name "$file" -exec zcat {} \; | \  # find the files with the given name and output their content
        gzip > "$target/${file##*/}"         # gzip the target file
done
```